# Extend the controller of a winch

Tags: microcontroller, dc-motor

I have here a winch (ramsey ATV 8), where I would like to add two limit switches and a RF receiver. I already designed a schematic of how I think it could be controlled, but I'm not sure if this will work. If possible, the uC should be supplied by the same battery as the winch, but I'm affraid that the distortion will cause to problems on the uC. Do you think this will work the way I planned? I would appreciate any improvements from your side.

Datasheet:

[image]
[image]

Schematic:

[image]

Comment: you're going to want a 5A fuse between the estop switch and the battery.

Comment: Ok, I will integrate the fuse. What is about L2, should I add there a inductor to supress distortion or could lead this to oszillation?

Comment: a diode would be better there.

Comment: your emergency switch could also cut the +12 that flows to the other two relay coils.

Comment: What is about the common ground? Can this lead to distortion that potentially could influence the behavior of the uC?

Comment: Ground it the vehicle chassis. if its impedance is too high for low speed digital signals you've got a serious rust problem.

Comment: Ok, thank you. The winch is not used in a car, but as a lift outside a house with loads up to 550kg. I decided to use a power supply and I found this one: http://cdn-reichelt.de/documents/datenblatt/D400/RSP_2000_XX.pdf It is rated for 100a +5% and from the datasheet of the winch i get a current of around 101a for 1200lbs. What i worry is, that the peak current at the startup could lead the supply to go into the short circuit protection mode and shut down the supply. Is this a real scenario and if yes, what could I do instead?